# nginx display only default server page

Tags: nginx

I have a standard and clean nginx installation following this recent tutorial:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

I wanna host my own prova.it(for example) domain and I configure correctly dns on my vultr vps

Now I have two files on `/etc/nginx/sites-available` folder:

**default:**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

**prova.it**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/prova.it/public_html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name prova.it www.prova.it;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Obviously I create the folder and an `index.html` file in `/var/www/prova.it/public_html`

My problem is that if I go to prova.it url I see the nginx standard home page (`/var/www/html/index.html`) instead my `/var/www/prova.it/public_html/index.html`

Answer (score 1):

/etc/nginx/sites-available is a folder that you can use to store your nginx configuration files. In order for the nginx to use your configuration, though, you have to place it in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled. Typically this is done using a symbolic link, i.e.:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/prova.it /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

then tell nginx to reload the configuration files

```
sudo service nginx reload
```